# ios NavigationBarHidden not working in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi I am new to swift IOS programming. I am having trouble hiding the navigation bar in function `viewDidLoad()`.

This is the code I have:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE
```

However it is not hiding the navigation bar once the view loads. Do I need to place more code somewhere else?

UPDATE:
Problem solved! Replaced the viewDidLoad() with viewWillAppear() and now it is working. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Replace that code in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad, and it should work properly

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is not the appropriate place for this, since your view controller is yet to be added to the navigation controller's stack. 
You should use `viewWillAppear` instead!

Answer (score 0):

The viewDidLoad() method is call only once when ViewController loads. 
You should try to put it in viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```